# Error creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka' versions of Kafka

Tags: spring-boot, spring-kafka, embedded-kafka

getting:

Error creating bean with name 'embeddedKafka'

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.codahale.metrics.Reservoir

```
 <kafka.version>2.8.1</kafka.version>
 <spring.kafka.version>2.8.1</spring.kafka.version>
```

springboot version: 2.6.3 - can't be changed

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-test</artifactId>

            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-kafka</artifactId>

        </dependency>
      
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
             <version>${spring.kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.boot.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
          
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <version>${spring.kafka.version}</version>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka-clients</artifactId>
            <classifier>test</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>kafka_2.13</artifactId>
            <classifier>test</classifier>
            <scope>test</scope>
            <version>${kafka.version}</version>
        </dependency>
```

Where is the conflict? Maybe is some other dependency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please, follow instructions in the docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.1/reference/html/#update-deps.

Consider to use the latest Spring for Apache Kafka in that generation: https://spring.io/projects/spring-kafka#learn.

It looks like something brings incompatible Zookeeper version and we have a special comment for that in the docs for the mentioned version:

```
<!-- needed if downgrading to Apache Kafka 2.8.1 -->
<exclusions>
    <exclusion>
        <groupId>org.apache.zookeeper</groupId>
        <artifactId>zookeeper</artifactId>
    </exclusion>
</exclusions>
```

**UPDATE**

This pom works for me:

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.3</version>
    <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>
<groupId>com.example</groupId>
<artifactId>so-73113638</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<name>so-73113638</name>
<description>so-73113638</description>
<properties>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <kafka.version>2.8.1</kafka.version>
</properties>
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
    </dependency>

    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
        <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>
```

I just provide a `kafka.version` property and rely on the Spring Boot feature to manage deps for me.

Comment: That's for 2.9.x + when downgrading from the 3.0.x clients and later; we only pull it in as an `api()` in the gradle build.

Comment: Yeah... We don't say that in the doc, only this `When using 2.8.1, you also need to exclude zookeeper dependency from spring-kafka-test.`. Anyway that's strange to use `spring-kafka-2.8.1`, when there is already `2.8.8`. Also not clear the reason behind using Apache Kafka `2.8.1`, when it is much better to rely on whatever Spring Boot brings for us...

Comment: zookeeper 3.6.3 comes from  org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka-test:jar:2.8.1:test
when I ran dependency tree

Comment: Why don't rely on whatever that Spring Boot version brings for you: https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/blob/v2.6.3/spring-boot-project/spring-boot-dependencies/build.gradle#L1672 ?

Comment: I just removed the spring.kafka.version property and fail on same, tree shows org.springframework.kafka:spring-kafka:jar:2.8.2

Comment: Correct. And now remove `kafka.version` as well. Plus respective manual deps. Just rely on the transitive deps from `spring-kafka-test`

Comment: kafka.version version is required there for org.apache.kafka:kafka-clients:jar:test and org.apache.kafka:kafka_2.13:jar:test is missing

Comment: Where?  If you remove `kafka-clients` and `kafka_2.13`, the proper version should be brought by the `spring-kafka-test` transitively.

Comment: See its pom: https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/kafka/spring-kafka-test/2.8.2/spring-kafka-test-2.8.2.pom. Or you just want to downgrade to Kafka Client from that default `3.0.0` just because it has some problem on Windows? Then you need to follow the docs I've mentioned in my answer: https://docs.spring.io/spring-kafka/docs/2.8.1/reference/html/#update-deps. It just does exactly what you'd like to hear from us, with only difference that it does not override Spring for Apache Kafka version.

Comment: I removed those 2 dependencies and now fail on ClassNotFoundException: io.micrometer.core.instrument.binder.system.DiskSpaceMetrics

Comment: See an UPDATE in my answer. So, I rely on `spring-kafka` version from Spring Boot and just override a version property for Kafka Client. The rest of "magic" is done for me by Spring Boot dependency management.

Answer (score 0):

You need to use Zookeeper 3.6.3; Kafka no longer pulls it in transitively.

Comment: to which which minimal versions of   kafka.version and 
spring.kafka.version with springboot 2.6.3 I can take in order not to use zookeeper?

Comment: You cannot get rid of it. You use embedded Kafka which is essentially Kafka Broker by itself. And that one requires Zookeeper to run.

Comment: Newer brokers (3.x, I think) can be run in Raft mode (no ZK needed), but it might still be experimental, I am not sure; we haven't switched the embedded broker to RAFT mode yet.

Comment: Thanks , Gary, for education! Anyway see my answer: looks like that works for downgrading